# Trouble with 301 redirect of old naked domain to new domain

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect

Using `.htaccess` I am trying to setup a simple 301 redirect which redirects both `exampleA.com` and `www.exampleA.com` (the old domain) to `exampleB.com` (the new domain). However, accessing `www.exampleA.com` results in a 403 Forbidden status.

Both `exampleA.com` and `exampleB.com` point to the same hosting account.

So, in summary:

- `http://exampleA.com` redirect to `http://exampleB.com` - OK
- `http://www.exampleA.com` redirect to `http://exampleB.com` - 403 Forbidden

.htaccess code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampleA\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exampleA\.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exampleB.com/$1 [L,R=301]]
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*(default|index)\.(html|php|htm)\ HTTP/ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)(default|main|index)\.(html|php|htm)$ http://exampleB.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Note: I am making these changes in the htaccess file of the current new domain website.

1. How do I need to change the syntax to redirect both non-www and www to the new domain without getting a 403 response?
2. If I make changes to the htaccess file are these reflected instantly or do they take time?

Comment: `I am making these changes in the htaccess file of the current new domain website.` Err? You can't do that unless they share the same file space, which isn't a good idea. You should use two .htaccess files, one for the old domain and where that is hosted, i.e `/var/www/public_html/exampleA.com` and then another in `/var/www/public_html/exampleB.com`. Your exampleA (old domain should redirect everything to the new domain, no need to setup rules in the .htaccess for the new domain.

Comment: Thanks Simon - Thanks Simon - in reply. I changed the domain by mapping the old domain to the new domain but not And kept the original web site. Then I changed all the old domain URLs to the new domain. But am only struggling with the redirect of the naked domain - whatever I have done redirects fine the www.olddomain.co.uk but not the olddomain.co.uk

Comment: If you have changed the site file paths to the same web root, then you do not need to do a redirect. This is a good solution. But for those who are confused on these issues, I recommend against it. Before your change, your redirects from site A to site B would have to been made within the site A .htaccess file and not site B.

Comment: @closetnoc You'll need to do a redirect if need to move the user from `exampleA.com` to `exampleB.com`?

Comment: Your code looks "OK" - it's not obvious why the naked (old) domain fails to redirect, but the `www` apparently redirects ok. (You should add this fact to your question, since your question states that _all_ requests for the old domain result in a 403. - _Ah, I see that information was removed in the edit!_) However, there's an obvious error/typo in the code you have posted, so I wonder if there is a typo in your "real" code?

Comment: @w3dk Please share the code I should have - considering only the naked domain fails to redirect

Comment: Also, clear your browser cache! Otherwise, like I say, your code looks OK. You could write the same thing in different ways, but it won't make a difference. The problem would seem to be somewhere else. The "typo" that I referred to is the additional `]` on the `RewriteRule` - that should be removed, however, it won't prevent this code from working; it will simply be ignored. The comment suggests this is a "WordPress" site, however, the directives you have posted don't look very WordPress? It's not clear what would trigger a 403, only when requesting the "naked" old-domain.

Comment: One thing that could trigger a 403 is if you didn't have an index document and directory indexes are disabled. However, if the `www` domain works then that can't be the problem - unless they somehow resolve to different locations?!

Comment: @w3dk My point is that redirecting from site A to site B, the code cannot be on site B, it must be on site A or it will not be seen. Perhaps I did not write my comment well. Sorry. Cheers! You got the OP; I know they are in the best hands possible.

Comment: @w3dk I have not moved the site. what I did was map the oldExample.com to the newExample.com and make the newExample.com the primary domain. I was then told to change the htaccess file (there is only one) which I did as above

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, what you already have is "OK" - it *should* work in terms of redirecting `exampleA.com` (both www and the naked domain) to `exampleB.com`. So I suspect the problem is *somewhere else*. However, what you have could be tidied and improved. So, I don't think this answer is really a solution, but a slightly different way of doing the same thing - which *might* help.

Since both the old and new domains point to the same place, you don't need to specifically check for the old domain. You can alternatively write... if it's not the new domain then redirect to the new domain. This will also handle your canonical `www` to `exampleB.com` redirect, which you have not currently implemented.

So, instead of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampleA\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exampleA\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exampleB.com/$1 [L,R=301]]
```

(Incidentally, you have an extra `]` at the end of the `RewriteRule` - although this won't result in an error, it will simply be ignored.)

Can be rewritten as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=exampleB.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://exampleB.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the request is not `exampleB.com` then redirect to `exampleB.com`. Note the `NC` flag on the `RewriteCond` directive. This is not for normal users (browsers always lowercase the host), but for bots/scripts that might make malformed requests.

> 2. If I make changes to the htaccess file are these reflected instantly or do they take time?

On a simple client/server setup they should be reflected instantly.

However, be careful of (browser) caching. 301 redirects are cached by the browser (and perhaps intermediary proxies). This includes any 301 "mistakes" you've previously requested. In Google Chrome you can run with the Object Inspector open and caching disabled. Alternatively, test with 302 (temporary) redirects (which are not cached) and only change to a 301 when you are sure it's working OK.

> `# BEGIN WordPress`

You have a comment that suggests WordPress, however, the directives don't look very WordPress to me?

Also, if you have other directives in your .htaccess file or server config they could be conflicting and causing this error.